# Can I have 2 controllers in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a small search app using Elasticsearch and AngularJS (still learning how to use both). I know this may not be best practice, but for all the AngularJS code, trying to keep all my js code in 1 file.

I would like to use the AngularJS UI Bootstrap Typeahead for an autocomplete feature but a little confused on how I can have 2 controllers for the app OR if I can somehow include the Typeahead in my current controller?
Here is some of my code:

```
var searchApp = angular.module('searchApp', ['elasticsearch', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);

searchApp.controller('SearchResultsList', ['$scope', 'searchService', 'filterService', '$sce', function($scope, searchService, filterService, $sce) {
```

I've included ui bootstrap as a dependency for the app, but since I already have SearchResultsList as my controller, not sure how to include TypeaheadCtrl to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can have as many controllers as you'd like in AngularJS. You need to be careful however (for example passing variables between controllers, `$scope.$parent`, if applicable)

As well, if you are using type-ahead (or any directive from Angular UI-Bootstrap such as `tabset`), you need to be careful of child-scopes and primitive scopes creating be Angular-UI-Bootstrap. Always declare `scope` variables using some holding object so it doesn't get overwritten in primitive scopes in a directive (`$scope.data` storing your data vs just storing it in `$scope`)

For including typeahead, this is a simple directive and you've already included its functionality when you included it as a dependency in the module. Just read the documentation and follow it:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/